# Type Casting in cin ( C++ )

Tags: c++, type-conversion

```
    int x;

    cout << "Enter an integer :: " << endl;
    cin >> x ;
    cout << "Your value is = " << x << endl;

    cout << "Enter a float :: " << endl;
    cin >> float (x) ;
    cout << "Your value is = " << x << endl;
```

The above code shows error. Why is it that I can type cast in cout but not in cin ?

Comment: cin requires an l-value reference, but when you cast to float it becomes an r-value reference. cout can take both r and l value references.

Comment: It looks like you're trying to use `x` to store both an `int` and a `float`. C++ doesn't work like that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A cast like this:

```
  float(x)
```

produces a nameless temporary object of type `float`. The >> operator effectively looks like this:

```
 istream & operator>>( istream &, float & f );
```

and you can't bind  a non-const reference to a temporary.

The output operator effectively looks like this:

```
 ostream & operator<<( ostream &, const float & f );
```

and you *can* bind a const reference to a temporary, so this works.